# What does Function declared without curly braces means in Dart?

Tags: dart

I saw a tutorial where he declared a function like this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Function(String name) doingHobby;
}
```

What does it mean? how is it differ with common Function with bracket?
This also not even looks like arrow function.

Thanks.

Comment: That is declared as object type or variable in other terms. Its the same a String, Int, etc. But in that case hes using Function(String) as and object. Which only takes a Function value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `doingHobby` is a variable which is allowed to point to as function which returns `dynamic` (if we don't specify any return value, Dart will assume `dynamic` which basically means it is allowed to return anything including `void`) and takes one `String` argument.

Here is an example where I assign a `void Function(String)` to it using a constructor and later calls this function by using the `doingHobby` variable:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  void Function(String name) doingHobby;

  Person(this.name, this.doingHobby);
}

void main() {
  final person = Person(
    'Jakob',
    (hobby) => print('Doing $hobby'),
  );
  person.doingHobby('playing football'); // Doing playing football
}
```

Comment: Specifically, this is an example of an Inline Function Type: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs

Comment: @julemand 
may i know is there a difference between var person = Person() and Person person = Person()?

Comment: Well, if it is kinda obvious what the type of an object is based on its name, it does not really make sense to also specify the type. So using `var`/`final` in my example lets Dart automatically determine what type the variable should be at compile time. So since `person` is assigned a `Person` object, the type of `person` is automatically set to `Person`. So if possible, I am just letting Dart setting the type on my variables inside methods and only specify types on class members and parameters/return value of methods.

Comment: The use of `final`/`var` can actually prevent some problems if you are working with e.g. `List` since it often have a generic type. If e.g. you are doing: `List list = List<int>[]`, the variable `list` will actual be assigned the type `List<dynamic>` where if you have used `var`/`final`, Dart would have assigned type type `List<int>` to `list`. So letting Dart assigning the type can end up making your code more type safe in some situations if you are not aware of what you are doing with your typing. :)